# Increasing the performance of an iterating function with Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, sum

Is there a way I could run the function below on pure numpy, so I am trying to get rid of the for loop. I am trying to decrease the runtime of my code. `Number_array` is added on with each each element of `Values`and summed. The sum  is appended onto the `Appending_list` after each iteration. The `Number_array`  makes 10000000 integers between 0 to 100.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
Appending_list = []
Values = random.randint(100, size=(100000))
Number_array = random.randint(100, size=(1000))
for n in range(len(Values)):
    result = np.sum([Number_array + Values[n]])
    Appending_list.append(result)
```

Performance:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the obvious, computing `np.sum(Number_array)` only *once* and adjusting the sum for each value in `Values`?

Comment: That loop also isn't a problem, almost all work is done by NumPy already.

Comment: I dont undestand the adjustation of the sum bit? I understand that the for loop doesnt slow it down much but that was because the length of the n value was a so little. If I increase the length of the n value it will start to have its affects on procesing time. I have updated the code probably that would be a better example

Comment: Hmm, so you can't determine the difference between `np.sum([Number_array + Values[n]])` and `np.sum(Number_array)`? Or is your profile image accurate?

Comment: Oh i see what you mean, but if the len of values is very large that would affect the performance drastically as well. Since its iterating through a  for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for comparison:

```
Appending_list = []
for n in range(len(Values)):
    result = np.sum([Number_array + Values[n]])
    Appending_list.append(result)
```

Writing the sum a different way:

```
Appending_list = []
for n in range(len(Values)):
    result = np.sum(Number_array) + Values[n] * len(Number_array)
    Appending_list.append(result)
```

And that is easy to vectorize:

```
Appending_list = np.sum(Number_array) + Values * len(Number_array)
```

Comment: Certainly does impact the performance but the for loop bottlenecks it. Thanks anyways

Comment: What for loop? There isn't one anymore.

Comment: Oh never mind I thought the `Appending_list ` function was same as the `result`. Sorry about that.